# 'io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable' error

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm coding a Stroop task for an experiment with PsychoPy. I'm trying to draw the image and text stimuli, but I'm getting the error message (indicated below).

I've tried looking at google/stackoverflow pages, but don't understand this error messages (so it has been hard to fix this code).

```
# ------Prepare to start Routine "instructions"-------
t = 0
instructionsClock.reset()  # clock
frameN = -1
continueRoutine = True
# update component parameters for each repeat
ready = event.BuilderKeyResponse()
# keep track of which components have finished
instructionsComponents = [instrText, ready]
for thisComponent in instructionsComponents:
    if hasattr(thisComponent, 'status'):
        thisComponent.status = NOT_STARTED

#read stimuli file
trials = open('cog2.csv', 'rb')
imageFile = 0     #imageFile = trials[trialNumber][Column]
corrAns = 1       #corrAns = trials[trialNumber][Column]
Congruent = 2     #Congruent = trials[trialNumber][Column]
stimCat = 3       #stimCat = trials[trialNumber][Column]
Superimposed = 4  #Superimposed = trials[trialNumber][Column]
Word = 5          #word = trials[trialNumber][Column]

#turn the text string into stimuli
textStimuli = []
imageStimuli = []
for trial in trials:
    textStimuli.append(visual.TextStim(win, text=trials[Word]))  <---- ERROR
    imageStimuli.append(visual.ImageStim(win, size=[0.5, 0.5], image=trials[imageFile]))
```

I'm trying to write out draw stimuli from an excel document I uploaded (contained paths to jpg images, and words that I want to superimpose on the images).

Currently though, I'm getting the error message:

```
#### Running: C:\Users\Sophie\OneDrive\Spring '19\Research\PsychoPy\Bejj\Test_3_22_19.py #####
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sophie\OneDrive\Spring '19\Research\PsychoPy\Bejj\Test_3_22_19.py", line 203, in <module>
    textStimuli.append(visual.TextStim(win, text=trials[Word]))
TypeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

The `trials` variable is a file object (from `trials = open('cog2.csv', 'rb')`), and you're trying to access it as a list with `trials[Word]`, hence the error.

You should use the `csv.reader` method to read the file as CSV instead, so that `trial` would be assigned with each row as a list, and that you can access each column with an index as you intended:

```
import csv
for trial in csv.reader(trials):
    textStimuli.append(visual.TextStim(win, text=trial[Word]))
    imageStimuli.append(visual.ImageStim(win, size=[0.5, 0.5], image=trial[imageFile]))
```

Comment: I followed what you wrote, but another error came up: for trial in csv.reader(trials): _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)" I did a few things, and tried adding (encoder = utf-8) to trials = open('cog2.csv') but this didn't work either. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah yes, you should open the file in text mode. Please try `trials = open('cog2.csv', 'r')` instead of `trials = open('cog2.csv', 'rb')`.

Comment: I did try that too before, and it showed me a another error: TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable. So i've been going back between these two errors

Comment: Did you use `csv.reader` after you opened the file in text mode?

Comment: Yes I did - I wrote trials = open('cog2.csv', 'r'), which is under #read stimuli file, and then added the "for trial in csv.reader(trials):..." bit. But this was still the error that came up?

Comment: That has to be because you're using `trials[Word]` instead of `trial[Word]`. Please see my code above. You have to use `trail`[Word]` since `trial` is the `csv.reader` object, not `trials`, which is the file object.